# Is the use of 'Wingman' limited to only a man?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe **a girl** which helps **another girl** hook up with a guy while occupying the not-so-good-looking-one, just exactly what a wingman does! So can **that girl** be called a wingman or is there another term for her?

> *According to* [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingman_(social))
>   Wingman is a role that a person may take when a friend needs support with
>    approaching potential partners. A wingman is someone who is on the "inside" and
>    is used to help someone with intimate relationships. In general, **one person's wingman will help him or her avoid
>    attention from undesirable prospective 
>   partners or attract desirable ones, or both.**
>  
>   According to [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wingman)
>
> A Wingman is a guy you bring
>    along with you on singles
>   outings (like to bars) that helps you 
>   out with the women.

POST ANSWERS EDIT: I've highlighted a context in the definition which, I guess, does imply that wingman can be a girl helping another girl. But as @Josh suggested that wingman is implied for a man and also I can't find any references for a girl as a wingman.
wingwoman is indeed used for a woman(as @Josh posted) but a wingwoman is usually escorting a man trying to hook him up with a girl.

 UD(4th sense defines 'wingwoman' as-

> 'Unlike a Wing Man, this is not the girl who occupies the hot guy's
>    ugly friend,'

...and I'm looking for a word to describe **that** girl which helps another girl hook up with a guy while doing all that a wingman **actively** does.
I said 'actively' because UD( 6th sense)also defines it -

> The
>   wing women are frequently
>   spotted around the queen bee, the girls that comparatively make the head woman look better than she actually does.

So I'd like to know a word(noun) for that girl acting like a wingman. Also if she can be just called a 'wingman'(acc. to the highlighted part).

 I don't know how else to clarify it furthermore but I'd appreciate any help:)

Comment: Many people think little of using *-man/-men* words indiscriminately on both sexes.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using *wingman* for a female. Some corporations use *chairman* for females, eschewing or abandoning *chairperson*. And what about a handyman: you going to insist on calling a female a *handyperson*?

Comment: I have certainly heard, on TV and in movies, women refer to a female friend in a bar or at a party as a "wingman".  It has always seemed to be said with a "wink", though.

Answer (score 1):

There's several pages on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22wing+girl%22&start=30) dedicated to **wing girl**, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wing%20girl) provides two definitions, dated 2005 and 2008 respectively

> **1.** The attractive hot girl who will go out with a good guy friend when he needs to look good at a party or other social event. Not an escort, but a friend.
>
> guy friend:*Yo, will you be my wing girl for homeboy's birthday party?*
> girl friend: *Sure, as long as you pay for dinner.*

and

> **2.** Similar to the word wing man, but is a girl. **A wing girl is a girl who helps out a guy/girl friend to meet other people of the opposite sex**, someone who proves as an ice breaker. By no means like an escort service.
>
> *I'd have never had Kim as my girlfriend without my wing girl, Jen.*

Comment: I did consider 'wing girl' or 'wing woman', but I wasn't sure if it could be used **by a girl for a girl** to find a guy...but as the 2nd defination of UD suggests, I guess I can hold on to that. Is it used widely in **girly** context?

Comment: @Nikki in my view ***wing girl*** tells the listener/reader which sex they are, that they may help find a male or female partner/girl or boyfriend is secondary.  If I were to hear that someone called Pat or Kim was a *wing man* I'd assume they were a man. But if Pat or Kim were said to be a *wing girl* I'd know which sex they were. Does it make any difference? That's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

In lay Magistrates' Courts in England, the members of the bench normally appear as a threesome. The one presiding sits in the centre, and is known as Chairman (Mr or Madame Chairman), the ones on either side are called "wingers".

**I see nothing wrong with calling the people you describe as *wingers***.